# Function from Swift class can't be seen by Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a function in a Swift class that I want to call from an Objective-C class. I have declared the Swift class as an instance variable in the Objective-C class, but I can't seem to call a method from the Swift class on that variable. Here is some sample code to explain:

PhotoViewController.swift:

```
@objc class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {
    // other methods and variables

    postViewController = // defined
    postViewController.ingestViewController = self

    @objc public func submit(image: UIImage) {
        // does stuff
    }
}
```

PostViewController.h:

```
@class PhotoViewController;

@interface PostViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) PhotoViewController *ingestViewController;
@end
```

PostViewController.m:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@class PhotoViewController;

@interface PostViewController ()

@end

@implementation PostViewController

// other code

- (void)_done {
    [self.ingestViewController submit:self.scan];
}
@end
```

I continue to get the error: `No visible @interface for 'PhotoViewController' declares the selector 'submit:'`. I also tried making the PhotoViewController public and that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Let Xcode complete the call for you. Type `[self.ingestViewController submit` and see what it offers for completion. Probably `submitImage:`.

Comment: @rmaddy I allowed Xcode to complete the call and got: `[self.ingestViewController submitWithImage:self.scan.enhancedImage];` however, it doesn't seem like it's actually calling the `submit` method from `PhotoViewController` (I added a print in the method and nothing is printing)

Comment: @jordan We won't be able to help you without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You probably have a different instances of `PostViewController`, one that is displayed and one created in `PhotoViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy why is `submitWithImage` the same as `submit`?

Comment: It's the way method signatures are translated between the two languages.